# I try to create an API Key but I obtain an error

Tags: sparkpost

I try to create an API but when I go in my dashborad and I create the new API key with all permission, when I click on the create button I obtain:

```
Looks like this action has been disabled for your account.
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check your email for an email from abuse@sparkpost.com. It's possible that your account could have been suspended.
It's also possible that you may be a reporting only user.

Comment: Aydrian I create another account but when I go to Sign up I obtain " an error occured" and I can't sign up!

Comment: Your best option is to create a [support ticket](https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/emails/new) with your original account. We can see what's going on.